# How do I limit google streetview response to strictly google panoramas?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-street-view

Is there any way for me to limit returned streetview pano's to only google instances. I tried setting `StreetViewSource.GOOGLE` for sources but still keep getting an outdated, non google pano which is strange to me. I haven't seen this being an issue until the recent changes that were introduced onto the map platforms

This is the lat lng that I am trying to access: 37.41229382514552, -79.19579734183662
It is resorting to [shentel communications](https://www.google.com/maps/@37.412205,-79.1955765,3a,75y,296.18h,90t/data=!3m7!1e1!3m5!1sAF1QipMVLRrmS6DhxajY8i8Q6-s20z3r-wwNzWR96UUn!2e10!5s20210121T000000!7i7680!8i3840?entry=ttu) pano and not google, even though there is a [more recent streetview pano](https://www.google.com/maps/@37.4122094,-79.1955885,3a,75y,296.18h,90t/data=!3m8!1e1!3m6!1sdSNhv4FrRzejYyyW7QXC5w!2e0!5s20231101T000000!6shttps:%2F%2Fstreetviewpixels-pa.googleapis.com%2Fv1%2Fthumbnail%3Fpanoid%3DdSNhv4FrRzejYyyW7QXC5w%26cb_client%3Dsearch.gws-prod.gps%26w%3D86%26h%3D86%26yaw%3D296.17957%26pitch%3D0%26thumbfov%3D100!7i16384!8i8192?entry=ttu) available.

```
async function findNearestStreetView(location, radius) {
    const {StreetViewService, StreetViewPreference, StreetViewSource} = await google.maps.importLibrary("streetView");
    
    var streetViewService = new StreetViewService();

    // Setting options for Street View request
    var streetViewOptions = {
        location: location,
        radius: radius,
        sources: [StreetViewSource.GOOGLE], // Limiting searches to official Google collections
        preference: StreetViewPreference.NEAREST
    };

    streetViewService.getPanorama(streetViewOptions, function(result, status) {
        if (status === 'OK') {
            // Found an official Google panorama within the given radius
            panorama.setPosition(result.location.latLng);
            panorama.setPov({ heading: 0, pitch: 0 });
            // Optionally, you can send metadata to the server or handle it as needed
            sendMetadataToServer(result.location);
        } else {
            console.log('No Google Street View available within the specified radius.');
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Open a new bug in the [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=status:open%20componentid:188853).

Comment: You can report this type of data issue using the 'Send Feedback' feature on Google Maps.

Comment: @Kat we're talking about the API here, not the Google Maps website. The way to report issues is via the [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=status:open%20componentid:188853).